# Handling Nested flatMap/Map in reactive programming

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, reactive-programming

I have an api to get the details of Employees and using some of the data from the Employee details response would be trying to call another service(employeePerformanceService). This basically returns some additional details of the employee regarding his Salary.
Finally, I need to get the complete info about the employee.
Basically, need to get the employee details even if employeePerformanceService fails to return any value.

But the issue happens in a scenario where employeePerformanceService call is not able to return any value due to service unavailable.
In that case, employeePerformanceService will return a Mono.empty().
But that is not working since the map doesn't accept the null values and further processing is stopped.

Is there a different approach in Reactive programming to handle this type of scenario

```
public Mono<Employee> getEmployeeDetails(empId) {
    

        return employeeClient.getDetails(requestConfiguration, empId)
            .flatMap(empDetails -> employeePerformanceService
                .getAppraisalDetails(empDetails)
                    .map(response -> responseTranslator.translate(empDetails, response))
            )
            .doOnEach(LoggingUtils.logOnError(error -> log.error("message='Failed to get Employee details "
                    + " due to exception.' exceptionMessage='{}' referringTID={} token={}",
                error.getMessage(), "156464", token)));
}
```

Comment: "_But the issue happens in a scenario where employeePerformanceService call is not able to return any value due to service unavailable._" So a client makes a call for service that's not available or becomes unavailable. Seems to me you need to implement a timeout so that you could return `Mono.empty()`. If the service is available or becomes available and returns `null`, you could use `Optional` to make use of `orElse()` in order to return `Mono.empty()`.

Comment: "_Basically, need to get the employee details even if employeePerformanceService fails to return any value._" Can you explain how do you expect handling of such issues - ignore the error, retry, or something else?

Comment: @DenisKurochkin Expect that - ignore the error and continue to do .map(response -> responseTranslator.translate(empDetails, response)).

Comment: 1. What is `Mono`? 2. How can you recognise `Mono.empty()`? The response is that *usually* you should have some sort of noop structure and I'd expect whatever `Mono.empty()` is to not really cause an issue. If you say it does, then you can `.filter()` it but without knowing what it is or how to recognise the empty values I find it hard to give anything more concrete.